# Check repeated values in a dataframe and implement a ignoreNulls parameter

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I created a function to check if there is repeated values in a dataframe based on a Seq of columns.

I want to implement an "ignoreNulls", to be passed as a Boolean parameter into the function

- If true, will ignore and not group and count the nulls values. So for the nulls values, the "newColName" will return false.
- If false (default), will consider nulls values as a group and return true if theres multiples values with nulls for the key that I'm checking.

I don't know how could I do this.
Should I use an `if` or `case`?
There's some expression to ignore nulls on partitionBy statement?

Anyone could help me?

Here's the current function

```
def checkRepeatedKey(newColName: String, keys: Seq[String])(dataframe: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val repeatedCondition = $"sum" > 1
    val windowCondition   = Window.partitionBy(keys.head, keysToCheck.tail: _*)

    dataframe
      .withColumn("count", lit(1))
      .withColumn("sum", sum("count").over(windowCondition))
      .withColumn(newColName, repeatedCondition)
      .drop("count", "sum")
  }
```

Some test data

```
  val testDF = Seq(
      ("1", Some("name-1")),
      ("2", Some("repeated-name")),
      ("3", Some("repeated-name")),
      ("4", Some("name-4")),
      ("5", None),
      ("6", None)
    ).toDF("name_key", "name")
```

Testing the function

`val results = testDF.transform(checkRepeatedKey("has_repeated_name", Seq("name"))`

Output (without the ignoreNulls implementation)

```
+--------+---------------+--------------------+
|name_key|       name    |  has_repeated_name |
+--------+---------------+--------------------+
|     1  |      name-1   |              false |
+--------+---------------+--------------------+
|     2  | repeated-name |               true |
+--------+---------------+--------------------+
|     3  | repeated-name |               true |
+--------+---------------+--------------------+
|     4  |      name-4   |              false |
+--------+---------------+--------------------+
|     5  |         null  |               true |
+--------+---------------+--------------------+
|     6  |         null  |               true |
+--------+---------------+--------------------+
```

And with the ignoreNulls=true implementation should be like this

```
-- function header with ignoreNulls parameter
def checkRepeatedKey(newColName: String, keys: Seq[String], ignoreNulls: Boolean)(dataframe: DataFrame): DataFrame = 

-- using the function, passing true for ignoreNulls
testDF.transform(checkRepeatedKey("has_repeated_name", Seq("name"), true)

-- expected output for nulls
+--------+---------------+--------------------+
|     5  |         null  |              false |
+--------+---------------+--------------------+
|     6  |         null  |              false |
+--------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should define properly the logic in case that only part of the columns in `keys` are null - should it be counted as *null values* or *null value* is defined only if all the columns in `keys` are null?

For the sake of simplicity, lets assume that the there is only one column in `keys` (you can easily extend the logic for multiple columns). You can just add a simple `if` into your `checkRepeatedKey` function:

```
def checkIfNullValue(keys: Seq[String]): Column = {
// for the sake of simplicity checking only the first key 
    col(keys.head).isNull
}


def checkRepeatedKey(newColName: String, keys: Seq[String], ignoreNulls: Boolean)(dataframe: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    ...
    ...

    val df = dataframe
      .withColumn("count", lit(1))
      .withColumn("sum", sum("count").over(windowCondition))
      .withColumn(newColName, repeatedCondition)
      .drop("count", "sum")
    
    if (ignoreNulls) 
        df.withColumn(newColName, when(checkIfNullValue(keys), df(newColName)).otherwise(lit(false)) 
    else df
  }
```